# Getting rid of cPanel's default page

Tags: linux, apache, cpanel

I've uploaded my site to my public_html folder, however I'm still getting the default cPanel page.

I've tried using both index.html and index.php files with no success. For some reason it's not realizing that I've got a valid home file in there.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this fixed?

Comment: Can you access index.html when you access the file through your domain? ex www.mysite.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your domain is configured to point to account IP address. Account IP address you can see in your cPanel user interface in the left info section. Finally, DNS A record of your domain should be equal to it.